# Shell script to merge selected images to gif

Tags: shell-script, ffmpeg

I'm trying to write a simple shell script that I can use in my file manager Dolphin to merge selected images to GIF.
The following don't work, and I can't figure out the reason:

```
OUTPUT="$(kdialog --title "Merge to GIF" --inputbox "Please enter new file name:").gif"
INPUT="$(echo ${@} | sed -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/' -e 's/ /" "/g')"
convert -delay 60 "$INPUT" "$OUTPUT"
```

Comment: one issue is that `"$INPUT"` is going to be provided as one single argument, unlike `$INPUT` which would be split according to `IFS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why that one doesn't work, but this works:

```
OUTPUT="$(kdialog --title "Merge to GIF" --inputbox "Please enter new file name:").gif"
convert $(for i in "${@}"; do printf -- "-delay 60 %s " "$i"; done;) "$OUTPUT"
```